# Using find() to search for nested keys in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

This is going to be a silly question, but if I have a Mongo object that is in this format:

```
{
    "url": "google.com",
    "statusCode": 301,
    "headers": {
        "location": "http://www.google.com/",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        "date": "Fri, 22 Mar 2013 16:27:55 GMT",
        "expires": "Sun, 21 Apr 2013 16:27:55 GMT",
        "cache-control": "public, max-age=2592000",
        "server": "gws",
        "content-length": "219",
        "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
        "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN"
    }
}
```

Using `db.collections.find()`, how do I find the `server` key, or any key that is nested within another key?

I have tried `db.collections.find({headers:{server:"gws"}})`

I have tried quoting them in all possible combinations, but the output has always been blank, or `...`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Great question! All pymongo tutorials never use a nested key!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to use dot notation to get what you're looking for.  It would look like:

```
db.collections.find({"headers.server":"gws"})
```

In your query, what you're asking for is documents where `headers` is an object that looks like `{server: "gws"}`, so that only work if you know what the *entire* subdocument is.

Comment: will this work smoothly even when there are large user datasets?

Comment: @galeej Sorry, I haven't used Mongo in 7 years so I'm no longer very familiar with the performance characteristics.  I suspect that it will be quite fast as long as the field you're querying is indexed, though.

Comment: Very useful answer as PyMongo examples only use a shallow dict