# Dictionary of dictionary - python Mongo Db

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

I want find value - `db.mycol.find({"title":"Reuters"})`

```
{'_id': ObjectId('63b8dfbfd651efc35007b66c'), '18998750': {'pageid': 18998750, 'ns': 0, 'title': 'Reuters', 'extract': 'Reuters ( (listen), ROY-terz) is a news agency owned by Thoms
```

```
db = clu["Collections"]

col = db["wik"]

col.find({"title":"Reuters"})
```

Results - None.

Comment: I believe `col.find({"title":"Reuters"})` will only work if `title` is a direct key in the document, which it is not.  It is a sub-key underneath the top-level key `18998750`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use dot notation to get what you're looking for. Something like this:

```
col.find({"18998750.title":"Reuters"})
```

In this query, what you're asking for is documents where 18998750 is an object that looks like `{"title": "Reuters"}`, so this works if you know the entire subdocument.

Here are a couple of related questions:

[nested queries in pymongo using collection.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515195/nested-queries-in-pymongo-using-collection-find)

[Using find() to search for nested keys in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575373/using-find-to-search-for-nested-keys-in-mongodb)

And some references:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/using-find-to-search-for-nested-keys-in-mongodb

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-nested-documents-mongodb-with-python-pymongo/101554/4

Comment: thank you for support @florianc63 , I'd better change the parameters request